# php find and remove from content img string

Tags: web-scraping, str-replace, explode

I have a little problem, how correct can i find img src string who ends with dealer.jpg and remove only this string from my content? for example:

```
<?php
$content = '<b>this is a content</b><img src=http://adress.com/as5.jpg><br> this is a content <img src=http://www.another-adress.com/dealer.jpg>';
$inf = explode("/dealer.jpg", $content);
$string = str_replace("<img src=\"$inf[0]/dealer.jpg\">", "", $content);
?>
```

I use this because I dont know image link, link always is another, but I know this link ends with dealer.jpg , and this script is not working... so can some one help me how correct do this ? normaly I whant to remove ads from page that i scraped. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you are trying to remove the `img` tag that ends with "dealer.jpg" (no matter the domain), right? try this:

```
$content = '<b>this is a content</b><img src=http://adress.com/as5.jpg><br> this is a content <img src=http://www.another-adress.com/dealer.jpg>';
$content = preg_replace('/<img src=[A-z0-9-_":\.\/]+\/dealer\.jpg>/', '', $content);
var_dump($content);
```

**Edit**

This second example will match the `img` tag even if it has another attributes such as `alt`, `width`, etc (but again, must end with "dealer.jpg")

```
$content = '<b>this is a content</b><img src="http://adress.com/as5.jpg"><br> this is a content <img alt="dealer-image" width="120" height="40" src="http://www.another-adress.com/dealer.jpg">';
$content = preg_replace('/<img[A-z0-9-_:="\.\/ ]+src="[A-z0-9-_:\.\/]+\/dealer\.jpg">/', '', $content);
var_dump($content);
```

Obs: I changed the initial `$content` because i've noticed it was missing the double quotation for `src` attribute. Not sure if was a typo or your string really looks like this.

**Edit 2**

Here is a example using DOM (a guess that is the best aproach here since the order of attributes could change):

```
$content = '<b>this is a content</b><img src="http://adress.com/as5.jpg"><br> this is a content <img alt="dealer-image" width="120" height="40" src="http://www.another-adress.com/dealer.jpg">';

// creates a DOMDocument based on your string, and wraps it in a div
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<div>{$content}</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

// get all img tags
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) { // if they have that src, remove it from $dom
    if (strpos($img->getAttribute('src'), 'dealer.jpg')) {
        $img->parentNode->removeChild($img);
    };
}

// get all the content of my first div, and print it
$newContent = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
foreach ($newContent->childNodes as $childNode) {
    var_dump($dom->saveHTML($childNode));
}
```

Comment: forgot ask how to add:
 alt="dealer-image" width="120" height="40" />  
in this preg replace script??

Comment: Thanks but problem is that my img src string is: img src="http://www.another-adress.com/dealer.jpg" alt="dealer-image" width="120" height="40" i tried edit your script, but not working.... preg_replace('/<img src="[A-z0-9-_:\.\/]+\/dealer\.jpg"+[A-z0-9-_:="\.\/ ]>/', '', $content);

Comment: I'm starting to think the best approach here is using DOM instead of regex. Updated the answer with a example. The code looks bigger, but it's more precise i guess.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!